# Rename [smartfox] to [smartfoxserver]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

A quick google search about [smartfox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartfox) has smartfoxserver as the top result, and the only software technology result.

There already is a [smartfoxserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartfoxserver) tag, and it seems the correct name is SmartFoxServer, not SmartFox.

So I assume the tags should be merged?

Comment: A look at questions tagged `smartfox` shows that some of them wield both tags in the confusion too.